# React Navigation - Pass params when navigating in BottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using `BottomTabNavigator` from `react-navigation` in my React Native project.

I have `TAB A` and `TAB B`. I need to pass params from A to B.

In Screen A:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('B', {
            param: 'Test'
        });
```

In Sceen B:

```
const param = this.props.navigation.getParam('param');
```

`param` is always `undefined`. How to get the params in `B`?

Is this because `B` not re-render when I call `navigate`? There is no `componendDidUpdate` called in `B`.

Answer (score 1):

[Navigation lifecycle](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-lifecycle.html)
**React Navigation lifecycle events:**

> React Navigation emits events to screen components that subscribe to
>   them. There are four different events that you can subscribe to:
>   willFocus, willBlur, didFocus and didBlur. Read more about them in the
>   API reference.

This is what I need to achieve what I asked.
Example:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            alert: false
        };
        this.formikRef = React.createRef();
        this.didBlur = this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', payload => {
                if (payload.action.params)
                    this.setState({alert: payload.action.params.alert || false})
            }
        );
    }
// Do not forget to remove listener when component unmount
componentWillUnmount() {
        this.didBlur.remove();
    }
```